# Why isn't $('embed').remove working?

Tags: jquery

Trying to play a drum roll until a random name is generated, then remove it and play a cheering sound.

Both of these files start playing correctly, but for some reason the drum roll won't stop.

```
Array.prototype.remove = function(from, to) {
    var rest = this.slice((to || from) + 1 || this.length);
    this.length = from < 0 ? this.length + from : from;
    return this.push.apply(this, rest);
};

$(document).ready(function(){

    var staff = [ 'hardcoded', 'list', 'of', 'staff', 'members' ];

    $('button#start').click( function() {

        $('embed').remove();
        $('body').append('<embed id="drum-roll" src="drum-roll.wav" autostart="true" hidden="true" loop="true">');

        var $display = $('#display'),
            $results = $('#results table');
        $display.removeClass( "winner" );
        $display.addClass( "spinner" );

        var counter = 0,            
            rand = 0,
            run_time = 10,
            delay = ( run_time * 100 ) / staff.length,
            loop_number = 5,
            max_count = staff.length * loop_number;

        $display.doTimeout( 'loop', delay, function() {
            counter++;
            var newRand = Math.floor( Math.random() * staff.length );
            if ( rand === newRand ) {
                rand = Math.floor( Math.random() * staff.length );
            } else {
                rand = newRand;
            }

            $(this).text( staff[rand] );

            if ( counter < max_count ) { return true; }
            else {
                $('#results tr:last').after('<tr><td class="number">' + staff.length + '</td><td>' + staff[rand] + '</td></tr>');
                staff.remove( rand );
                $display.removeClass( "spinner" );
                $display.addClass( "winner" );

                $('embed').remove();
                $('body').append('<embed src="cheering.wav" autostart="true" hidden="true" loop="false">');
            }
        });
    });

});
```

Any ideas why this might be the case? I'm guessing it's something to do with the first `embed` not being in the DOM, or something?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: maby after appending the first drumroll: $('body').append('<embed id="drum-roll" src="drum-roll.wav" autostart="true" hidden="true" loop="true">', function(){  THE REST OF THE CODE   });

Comment: Have you tried `$('embed').prop("src", null).remove();`

Comment: Just tried that now @Esailija, same problem. Must be DOM-related, i.e. the `embed` doesn't exist when I'm trying to remove it? I'm no expert (that's probably quite clear..)

Comment: have you tried what i said? because the element would excist in the function

Comment: Hi @Gijs, my entire script breaks if I do that..!

Comment: a yes i'm sorry, maybe you could put a div in de dom thats not visible and append the embed to that and then clear the div (not remove it but just empty it)

Comment: An excellent idea, but unfortunately it hasn't worked :(

Comment: can you share your code in jsfiddle or something?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14169/discussion-between-gijs-and-dunc)

Answer (score 2):

Don't try to remove the "embed" tag, but a reference to the ID on the tag itself if you can.

Instead of:

```
$('embed').remove();
```

Try:

```
$('#drum-roll').remove();
```